# Training routine via docker image nvcr.io/nvidia/torch is 41% slower

Tags: docker, nvidia, torch, luajit, nvidia-docker

I train a DNN via NVidia docker image nvcr.io/nvidia/torch. Everything works fine except that it is far slower (+41%) than the training time when executed on my machine. One batch execution takes around 410ms instead of 290ms on bare metal.

My nvidia-docker run command:

```
nvidia-docker run -it --network=host --ipc=host -v /mnt/data1:/mnt/data1 my-custom-image bash
```

my-custom-image is based on nvcr.io/nvidia/torch. I only add my training scripts (.lua) and install luajit.
All results are written in /mnt/data1 and not inside the container itself.

Is it normal or am I doing something wrong? How can I investigate where wasted time comes from?

Update: I double checked and nothing is written inside the container during the training. All data are written on /mnt/data1.

Update2: I tried the inference routine inside the container, and it doesn't take more time than bare metal setup.

Comment: Try `nvidia-docker run --cpus 2 -it --network=host --ipc=host -v /mnt/data1:/mnt/data1 my-custom-image bash` and see if it helps?

Comment: I tried with --cpus 2 and --cpus 6.. and it's far slower ! Around 1200ms with 2 cpus and 800ms with 6.
The training routine works, of course, mostly on GPU

Comment: Are you able to provide your network running on synthetic data?

Comment: You should post on https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/200/nvidia-gpu-cloud-ngc-users/ for official NVIDIA support.

Comment: @ChristianSarofeen Unfortunately I can't. But it's similar to imageNet. Thanks for the link to the official NVidia support!